# Consolidate Two Columns into One List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns that I want to combine into one ordered column.

For example

First table:

| Name | Subname |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe |
| John | Doe |
| James | Doe |
| Frank | Smith |
| Kathy | Smith |
| Paul | Smith |

Second Table

| Name |
| --- |
| DOE |
| Jane |
| John |
| James |
| SMITH |
| Frank |
| Kathy |
| Paul |

I can get the same thing by using a pivot table but I am trying to add this information to a dashboard that will be used to copy and paste into an email.

Comment: So... what is the problem?

Comment: Or, making it more compact. `=LET(x,UNIQUE(B2:B7),
DROP(REDUCE("",UPPER(x)&","&BYROW(x,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A2:A7,a=B2:B7)))),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,TEXTSPLIT(z,,",")))),1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MS365` try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(B2:B7),
DROP(REDUCE("",UPPER(x)&","&BYROW(x,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A2:A7,a=B2:B7)))),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,TEXTSPLIT(z,,",")))),1))
```

---